# How do I hide a row in BIRT?

Tags: report, birt

I have a data table with 2 detail rows.  In certain cases I want to show the first detail row and in some cases I want to show the 2nd.  Something like:

```
if (row["field"] == "N") {
hideRow1();
}
else {
hideRow2();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In the layout tab in BIRT Report Designer, select the first detail row (so that it is higlighted).
- In the Properties tab of the Property editor for the row, select the Visibility section:

  - Check the Hide Element checkbox;
  - Click the `fx` button next to the Expression, and enter a formula like: `row["field"] == 'N'`.
- Repeat the process for the second detail row with a formula like: `row["field"] != 'N'`.

Comment: ,I want to hide the row if my result variable is empty, My code is below but its not working :
var val = JSON.parse(dataSetRow["deviceStatus.errorCode"])
var result="";
for(var t=0 ; t<val.length; t++)
{
if(val[t])
result = val[t] + ","+result
}
result != null

Comment: @Talib: That would be better asked as a new question, rather than as a comment on an existing answer.

Comment: I have posted another question but it is a bit different and its on Birt. please have a look if you can answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752325/creating-group-and-analyzing-data-from-array-list-in-birt