# creating group and analyzing data from array list in birt

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, birt

I am using mongo db in birt reports. I have data set which contains an array of object like in the picture.

[image]

deviceStatus is an array which contains child object like status,erroCode,deviceName etc.

I want to create the group for deviceName in the report when I create the group, it is created in this form :

```
[ "CardReader" , "CashAcceptor" , "CashDispenser" , "ChequeAcceptor" , "EmiratesIdScanner" , "PinPad" , "JournalPrinter" , "ReceiptPrinter" , "StatementPrinter" , "SignpadScanner"]
```

I want it to be grouped in the broken form like :

```
CardReader
CashAcceptor
CashDispenser ..
```

Also the errorCode is coming in this form from data set :

```
[ "97080301" , "97080302,97080303" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , ""]
```

In the same way I want to break the error code and status code from array form to each row for each deviceName like.

```
CardReader  97080301
CashAcceptor 97080302,97080303
CashDispenser
```

I am new to birt , please someone help. thanks in advance.

After Applying Veeram's answer , errorCode is not showing in the report but its there in preview results :

1 : 
[image]

2 :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to get the desired response.

Data:

```
db.devicestatus.insert([
  {
    "_id": "0001",
    "className":"store",
    "deviceStatus": [ {
    "deviceName": "CardReader",
    "errorCode": "97080301",
    "status": "Bad"
  },
  {
    "deviceName": "CashAcceptor",
    "errorCode": "97080302,97080303",
    "status": "Bad"
  },
  {
    "deviceName": "CashDispenser",
    "errorCode": "",
    "status": "Good"
  }]
  }
])
```

1.Data Explorer - Go to Data Sets - New Data Set - Select Data Source - Input Data Set Name - Click Next

[image]

2.Input collection name - devicestatus - Lists all the fields - Select Aggregate option from the command type dropdown - Click  Expression

[image]

3.Add the below expression in the expression builder prompt - Click OK

[image]

The below expression [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to flatten the array to decompose  devicestatus array into documents followed by [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)  to keep the required fields.

```
[
  {"$unwind":"$deviceStatus"},
  {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "className":1,
   "deviceStatus.deviceName":1,
   "deviceStatus.errorCode":1
   }
  }
]
```

OR

The below expression iterates over devicestatus array and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the required fields  followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to flatten to decompose the array into documents.

```
[{
  "$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "className":1, 
    "deviceStatus":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$deviceStatus",
        "as":"result",
        "in":{
          "deviceName":"$$result.deviceName",
          "errorCode":"$$result.errorCode"
        }
      }
    }
   }
 },
 {"$unwind":"$deviceStatus"}
]
```

OR

4.Confirm to refresh - Click yes

[image]

5.Move all available fields to the selected multi select drop box - Click Finish

[image]

6.Preview Results

```
{"className":"store", "deviceStatus":{"deviceName":"CardReader","errorCode":"97080301"}}
{"className":"store", "deviceStatus":{ "deviceName":"CashAcceptor","errorCode":"97080302,97080303"}}
{"className":"store","deviceStatus":{"deviceName":"CashDispenser","errorCode":""}}
```

Comment: thanks alot for the answer !!!! I will check and verify in a while  !! Thanks Again.

Comment: I am extremely thankful to you for spending time to answer this..It worked. I am very new to birt and mongo DB also.. Can you please explain what is the purpose of expression we wrote on data set??

Comment: Glad to help. You are welcome. Added some explanation and links.

Comment: thanks again, you are my teacher now... Everything looks fine now,, Just one thing ,errorCode is not coming in the reports while its there in preview results, I have updated the answer to include both the images,, Any Idea on it ?

Comment: You are welcome. Have never used birt reports. I'll recommend you to create a separate question for birt users so they can take a look with all the details.