# Getting duplicate rows on left join in Birt reports

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, reporting-services, birt, business-intelligence

I am joining two data sets in Birt . Its a left outer join. Below is the screen shot of the data sets.

[image]

The reason why I need all the rows of left table is I am doing some calculations on timestamp for all the rows of left table. I need to count the priority levels (how many times it occurred) in the right table if terminal Id matches with the left table.

When I get the records it gets the duplicate records which causes my timestamp calculations to get doubled.
I can't do inner join because I need to do the timestamp calculation from left table for must.

Relation of both the tables in many to many. I will explain with example what is the issue I am facing and what I want to achieve.
E.g. This is the data for the events of DeviceEventObject data set :

record 1 :

```
    "event" : "EXITED SUPERVISOR MODE",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-12-17T06:06:23.181Z"),
  "terminal" : {
            "terminalId" : "testterminal",
            "branchId" : "test"
        }
```

record 2:

```
 "event" : "ENTERED SUPERVISOR MODE",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-12-17T06:06:23.181Z"),
  "terminal" : {
            "terminalId" : "testterminal",
            "branchId" : "test"
        }
```

From this the timestamps of each event I am calculating the time between entered and exited events.

Now the other data set is DeviceStatusErrorCodePrioirtyLevel: 
E.g. This is the records in this data set :

```
"status" : "Online",
    "errorCode" : "123",
    "priorityLevel" : "test",
    "emailTypeCode" : "123",
    "terminal" : {
        "terminalId" : "testterminal",
        "branchId" : "test"
    }
```

Now I want to calculate the number of times the priority level "test" occurred for the terminalId "testterminal" . with the above data set count will be 1.
I am joining the both data sets on the basis of terminalId.

Now with the above data set I get duplicate records which doubles my time which I am calculating and also I get the count for the priority level 2.
For example this is what I get :

```
"event" : "EXITED SUPERVISOR MODE",   "priorityLevel" : "test"
"event" : "ENTERED SUPERVISOR MODE", "priorityLevel" : "test"
```

What I want is :

```
 "event" : "EXITED SUPERVISOR MODE",   "priorityLevel" : "test"
    "event" : "ENTERED SUPERVISOR MODE",
```

Additional Info of the birt project :

[image]

Sample data from both data sets :

```
DeviceStatusErrorCodePrioirtyLevel:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a36095f1854ad0b7096184b"),
    "className" : "com.omnia.pie.cm.models.snapshot.terminal.v2.DeviceStatusErrorCodePrioirtyLevel",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-12-17T06:06:23.181Z"),
    "deviceName" : "CardReader",
    "status" : "Online",
    "errorCode" : "123",
    "priorityLevel" : "test",
    "emailTypeCode" : "123",
    "terminal" : {
        "terminalId" : "testterminal",
        "branchId" : "test"
    }
}

DeviceEventObject:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3608c61854ad0b70961846"),
    "className" : "com.omnia.pie.cm.models.snapshot.terminal.v2.DeviceEventObject",
    "event" : "EXITED SUPERVISOR MODE",
    "value" : "True",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-12-17T06:03:50.901Z"),
    "transactionData" : {
        "transactionType" : "",
        "transactionNumber" : "",
        "sessionId" : ""
    },
    "terminal" : {
        "terminalId" : "testterminal",
        "branchId" : "test"
    }
}
```

Here is the link to my report in case :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dHOEneG2-fbeP9Mz86LUhuk0tSxnLZxi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can take a look. How did you set up birt reporting ? Did you follow any tutorial ?

Comment: Yes I followed some tutorial  to setup the birt project but I don't have the link of the tutorial at the moment. If you have any questions then you can ask me.. I will be very grateful if you can answer this.

Comment: @Veeram I have another question also related to Birt and mongoDb and has bounty on it, in case you wanna have a look : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752325/creating-group-and-analyzing-data-from-array-list-in-birt

Comment: I would love to but I'm not sure how to start here. Did you download some software or is it a eclipse plugin that you use ? How did you configure to use with eclipse ? Any information will help. There is not much online. If you can locate the link that would be helpful.

Comment: @Veeram First of all I had downloaded eclipse-reporting-neon then I created the birt project in eclipse following some tutorial ( I will look for the link ). I have updated the question to show you the project structure. To create the reports am not using some API called design engine API, I am just using the UI and script to put together the reports.
I also copied some jar files in the project and eclipse lib folder to support mongoDB.

Comment: @Veeram I think I followed this link just to setup the project : 
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/creating-simple-report-using-birt

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've answered the bounty question but I'm not able to reproduce the above issue. Can you share some data from both collections ? Is  field `terminal.terminalId` an type of array in any collection ?

Comment: @Veeram sorry I was out of town so could not reply .. terminal.terminalId is not an array . It is an object which contains two string...
I have updated the answer which shows sample data for both data sets.

Comment: Np. Is the relation one to one ? How are you counting the priority levels ?

Comment: I just want to match the terminalId in both data sets. If terminal Id from DeviceEventObject data set matches with DeviceStatusErrorCodePrioirtyLevel data set I want to count the priority level e.g. if there is terminalId for example "test" in event object data set and there are two priority levels lets say 'test' in other data set I want the result to be 2.
The problem I have I get DUPLICATE records on left joining the data sets in case of more than one records . I hope I make sense ?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes [using text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Also, you are not clear about what you want, so besides the example input & output you should be giving please use enough words & sentences to clearly say how output looks in terms of input.

Comment: @philipxy I think you are right the explanation was not enough. I have edited my question with examples also... please go through it if you have sometime to see if you can answer ?

Comment: @Veeram can you have a look at the question again.. I have edited it with example ..

Comment: Hi. I'll read your edited post. But you have not given an MCVE. You can make an SQL example at sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Thanks for providing all the details. There are two events in a first data set, exit and enter event with same terminal id. So when you join collections each document joins with document from second data set which produces two documents overall one for each event. I'm not sure but you can group on the first data set documents on some field to pick the first document followed by count of such documents. Do you have a grouping key that you can use ?

Comment: @Veeram yes when the two documents are created it cause issues as it double my priority count like it's suppose to be 1 but it becomes 2. I'm not sure if I can use any grouping key... In Birt I only have option to use joins for two data sets/collections.

Comment: You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to build the aggregation expression on first collection. Something like `[
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "secondcollection",
         localField: "terminal.terminalId",
         foreignField: "terminal.terminalId",
         as: "somealias"
       }
  }
]`

Comment: can you help me on that If you have time and If you don't mind?
I will have a look at the links you provided... Thanks

Comment: Np. You can add $group stage to the $lookup stage from the last comment to pick the first document based on the grouping key. Something like `{$group:{"$_id": group key here ( may be date ), doc:{"$first":"$$ROOT"}}` followed by count

Comment: Hi @Veeram both of these expressions needs to be running on joint data set or separately on the first and second data sets ?
I think its not possible to run the expression on join data set in birt.

Comment: No don't use the joint data set.  Run the first in a data set and add look up + group expression aggregate to pull in the second collection's data. lookup will also bring the same joined document twice, one for each enter and exit event. As mentioned in my previous comment, you will need a grouping key to logical process these multiple documents and reduce it to single document.

Comment: @Veeram thanks, I will try it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new data set for DeviceEventObject

Add the following aggregate function in the command expression builder.

The below function `$lookup` the data from status error code priority level based on terminalId followed by `$unwind` to flatten the data.

`$group` the flatten data on terminalId  to accumulate the distinct priority levels for a terminal id.

`$project` to count the distinct priority levels

```
[{$lookup:{
        from: "devicestatuserrorcodeprioirtylevel", // name of the collection
        localField: "terminal.terminalId",
        foreignField: "terminal.terminalId",
        as: "dsecpl"
}},
{$unwind:"$dsecpl"},
{$group:{
    "_id":"$terminal.terminalId", 
    "prioritylevels":{"$addToSet":"$dsecpl.priorityLevel"},
    "events":{"$push":"$event"}
}},
{"$project":{"prioritylevelcount":{"$size":"$prioritylevels"}, "events": 1} }
]
```

Move all the available fields to the selected fields column.

Preview results.